# RadGridView Selected Row

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, binding, telerik

I have a **Telerik GridView**. My **GridView** has several columns in it. The first column is a checkbox, and when I check or uncheck it, it changes a property in my *Model* named **IsSelected**!
The part of my code looks like this one:

```
<telerik:RadGridView>
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewColumn    Header="" 
                                       IsFilterable="False" 
                                       IsSortable="False" 
                                       IsReadOnly="True" 
                                       HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewDefaultCheckboxStyles}">
                <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                  Style="{StaticResource GridCheckBoxStyle}">
                        </CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewColumn>
            <!--Other columns-->
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Now I want to remove the checkbox, and when I click a row in my grid(anywhere in the row), I want the **IsSelected** property to change its value. How can I achieve that? 
I mean when I click a row, the selected row should be bound somehow to my **IsSelected** property, without braking the **MVVM** pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider adding a custom behavior to the GridView that listens to the selection changed event, and updates the IsSelected item. This should keep your design clean.